# D3: Select a circle by x and y coordinates in a scatter plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there any possibility in d3.js to select the elements by their position, i.e. by their x and y coordinates? I have a scatter plot which contains a large amount of data. And i have also an array of coordinates. the dots with these coordinates should be red. I am doing something like this for that:

```
bestHistory() {
            var that = this;
            var best = d3.select("circle")
            .attr("cx", that.runData[0].best_history[0].scheduling_quality)
            .attr("cy", that.runData[0].best_history[0].staffing_cost)
             .classed("highlighted", true)
        }
```

This method should set the class attribute of the circles on this certain positions equal to highlighted.

And then the appropriate CSS:

```
circle.highlighted {
    fill: red;
}
```

But instead getting red this dot just disappears.

How can I achieve that what I want to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the actual distance of each point to the point of interest and determine points color based on this distance like:

```
var threshold=...
var p =...
d3.select('circle').each(function(d){
    var x = p.x - d.x;
    var y = p.y - d.y;
    d.distance = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
}).attr('fill', function(d){
    return d.distance < threshold? 'red' : 'blue'
})
```

Ps. Sorry, answered from mobile